# Bash script issue with premmision for upload files

Tags: wordpress, bash

I have bash script for install WP. In end of bash file I have:

```
 chown $username. /home/$username/domains/$domain/public_html/.htaccess
```

After WP installation I can't upload any files to directory after `public_html/`

**note:** in `public_html` I can upload. Impossible upload to `wp-content, wp-admin, wp-includes` directory.

When I try set:

```
[user1@s1 public_html]$ chmod -R 777 wp-content/uploads
chmod: changing permissions of ‘wp-content/uploads’: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of ‘wp-content/uploads/2022’: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of ‘wp-content/uploads/2022/01’: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of ‘wp-content/uploads/2022/01/paxside_wp-150x53.png’: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of ‘wp-content/uploads/2022/01/paxside_wp.png’: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of ‘wp-content/uploads/material-wp’: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of ‘wp-content/uploads/material-wp/material-wp-dynamic.min.css’: Operation not permitted
```

So looks like this comand to grant user premision not do this to  directories?

```
chown $username. /home/$username/domains/$domain/public_html/.htaccess
```

Comment: Generally, only root can change ownership of files and directories. Other users don't have permission to do this, therefore you get "Operation not permitted" errors.

Comment: wp-content/uploads must be owned by Web server user. E.g. www-data on Ubuntu.

Comment: How can I do it  in bash script or now manually? Cloudlinux

Comment: `chown $username. /home/...`.  So you have a user that includes a dot `.` in the user name?  Let say `username=nic3500`, your code would result in `chown nic3500. /home/...`.  That dot is suspicious...